# Query 2 MYSQL tables to display certain results?

Tags: mysql, join, intersect

I will try to be short. I got two tables:

```
Users
ID | Name
1  | Joe
2  | Jimmy

Phone
ID | Number | User
1  | 12345  |  1
2  | 56789  |  2
```

Now I want generate a query to display all phones, but instead of showing the user number I want show his name.

Would be something like -> query * from phone ... while row ... echo $row->id, $row->number, $row->User+Name.

How can I do that? I can accomplish doing 2 queries, first 1 saving to an array and the second one modifying the elements of that array, but probably mysql got a better and faster solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: seems the site removed the line breaks.

Comment: Users / Phone = Tablename. ID/name, ID/Number/User = fields. 1/Joe and 2/Jimmy data from the Users table. 1/12345/1 Data from the Phone table

Comment: Use ctrl-K to format a block of text as code, or hit the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Phone.ID, Phone.Number, Users.Name
FROM Phone
LEFT JOIN Users ON Phone.User = Users.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

`select u.name, p.number from users u, phone p
where u.id = p.user`

unless phone doesn't know have an FK to user then use the outer join but only if there is a phone without a user